# Insert a row a table depending on outcome of INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

In mysql, using

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

It is possible to insert a row in a table, or just update it if it already exists.

Is there a way, in pure mysql, to then conditionally insert a row in a different table, depending on whether or not an insert or an update happened?

Answer (score 0):

```
drop PROCEDURE if EXISTS pro;
create PROCEDURE pro(a int)
begin
declare sign int;
insert into tab1(id) values(a) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id;
SELECT ROW_COUNT() into sign from dual;

if (sign=1) then
select 'yes' from dual;
else
select 'no' from dual;
end if;

end;
call pro(8);
```